# How to secure my api using node.js and only my app is using this api

Tags: ios, node.js, api

I want to create a iOS app, and I am starting to design a api using node.js+mongodb+express. I know people can use charles to set up a proxy and when user open the app in the iphone device, they can see the api requests in charles app. So people can use this api to do some harm to the app services or what. I want to secure my api. I won't open my api to others. So, I don't need oauth. What else I can do to secure my api? And if any tutorial is provided, that will be good.

Comment: Secure how? If your app can access it, so can anything else and that's pretty much that. You'll need to design the API so that malicious users can't screw anything up by sending requests separately.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with https, just make sure your app stops working if the certificate is invalid.

Alternative:
Crypt/decrypt your http(s)-body before sending/after receiving with a global password (not recommended) or a public key on your phone and a private key on your application.

If someone gets that pw or public key, they can still manipulate the API.

Comment: Note: Asymmetric key encryption (public/private key) is very slow and not used to encrypt data directly. Asymmetric key encryption is used to encrypt symmetric keys, the data is encrypted with with symmetric key encryption.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use https with additional security.

First: In the app "pin" the server certificate, that is validate  the server certificate in the app, this is quite common these days. AFNetworking supports this.

Second: Add a certificate to the app and verify it on the server. Now the server knows it is communication with your app.

Now both the server and app have assurance they are communication with authenticated end points.